# Grails/Groovy: URL params (max, offset) NumberFormatException thrown when blank/strings

Tags: url, grails, groovy, parameters, parseint

in the controller

```
 params.max = Math.min(params?.max?.toInteger() ?: 10, 20)
 params.offset = params?.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
```

if you enter in the following urls

```
/books?offset=10&max=              //error
/books?offset=10&max=sdf          //error
/books?offset=&max=10            //works
/books?offset=adsfa&max=10      //error


java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdf"

        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)

        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)

        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
```

Is there a one line groovy answer to check against null/string characters in the url params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Release Notes for Grails 1.2](http://bit.ly/cFC72s) where null safe converters for params and tag attributes were introduced.

You should change your lines..

```
params.max = Math.min(params?.max?.toInteger() ?: 10, 20)
params.offset = params?.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
```

..to the following code:

```
params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 10, 20)
params.offset = params.int('offset') ?: 0
```